# Set UIImageView Constraints programatically and activate the same

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, constraints

I have existing view in which I need to add `UIImageView` and `UILabel` at top below safe area.

Following is the way I create both `UIImageView` and `UILabel`

```
private var cardLbl: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textColor = .white
    label.text = "Hello User..."
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(style: .light, size: 14)
    label.accessibilityTraits = .header
    return label
}()

private var cardImg: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red
    return imageView
}()
```

Then by using these methods I add them on view

```
private func setupCardArtImage(){
        view.addSubview(cardImg)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cardImg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            cardImg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            cardImg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            cardImg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            cardImg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            cardImg.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 127)])
    }
```

and

```
private func setupCardArtName(){
        view.addSubview(cardLbl)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cardLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            cardLbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            cardLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cardImg.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            cardLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            cardLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)])
    }
```

Problem I am facing is, I am able to add `UILabel` successfully, but I am not able to add `UIImageView` successfully.

Following images you can see that I am able to see UILabel at top, but when I call method to UIImageView I am not able to get it.

[image]

[image]

Can any one please help me to understand what I am doing wrong and guide me with solution.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You haven't set `cardImg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` is your main problem. You are also over-constraining the image view. Either set leading/trailing constraints OR set center/width  constraints but not both; you will get conflicting constraint warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All thanks to @Paulw11 who help me quickly to get the solution.

Following is the code snippet with working solution.

```
private func setupCardArtImage(){
        cardImg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(cardImg)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cardImg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            cardImg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            cardImg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            cardImg.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 127)])
    }
```